# 'jquery' 'aja'x raising parser error, while getting data from laravel controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am  trying to get data from laravel controller, using 'jquery' ajax. However, i'm getting `parsererror`. According to the laravel documentation, it automatically sets a header `Content-Type= 'application/json'`, if we use `response()->json(data)`, and I tried setting the same header in ajax side too, but no difference.I also tried

```
        contentType:'application/json',
        dataType: "json",
        accept:'application/json',
```

but non of them worked. Here is my code setup:

```
   app.js

 var initlides = function () {
    return $.ajax({
        url: _url,
        contentType:'application/json',
        dataType: "json",
        accept:'application/json',
        success: function (data) {
          console.log(data)

        },
        error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown)
        }
    });
};



controller.php 

 public function index()
{
    echo $section;
    $carousels= array();
    $carousel = Carousel::where('section_name', 'intro')->get();
    return response()->json($carousel);
}
```

I searched for other similar questions, but non of them was helpful. Please help.

Comment: did you check if the controller return a json data ?

Comment: what's the method of the route (post/get/put etc ... )?

Comment: yes I did check it returns json data and its GET method

Answer (score 0):

[response()->json()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#other-response-types) accept only arrays that's why you are getting error, you have to use `Collection::toArray` method in order to transform your collection to array:

```
$carousel = Carousel::where('section_name', 'intro')->get()->toArray();
return response()->json($carousel);
```

**Or** just do:

```
$carousel = Carousel::where('section_name', 'intro')->get();
return $carousel->toArray();
```

Comment: Try to remove `contentType` and `accept ` headers from your ajax

Comment: already tried . I have tried all the possible combination of those three headers

Comment: Try with this ajax: `$.ajax({ url: _url, type: "GET", cache: false, success: ... });`